# How does CustomAuditEventRepository work?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jhipster, spring-boot-actuator

i have seen jhipster code for auditing `CustomAuditEventRepository`. But could  not understand how doe it work ?

I would like to add my own custom auditing for employee table just like `EmployeeAuditEvent` whenever employee get updated. How it can be done in jhipster?

Comment: Was my answer sufficient or do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

`CustomAuditEventRepository` handles authentication events in JHipster, not entity events. It is based on Spring Boot's Authentication Auditing Support. See this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit

The module https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-entity-audit allows generic entity auditing, and you could extend `AsyncEntityAuditEventWriter` to add custom behaviour based on entity type.

You can also check https://javers.org/ that provides a powerful solution for entity auditing.